# Add an aditional letter to R squared for annotate in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, superscript

I guess it is a very easy question, but I am not able to solve the problem.
I am fitting a linear mixed effect model and I would like to insert the marginal and the conditional R squared in my plot. For that reasons I want to to label them:

R²m = 0.65

R²c = 0.75

With that code I get the R²:

```
annotate(geom = 'text', label = paste("R^2 == ", 0.65), parse = TRUE)
```

However, I tried to play around with that code but I was not able to get the letter behind my R².
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to use `bquote` instead. This will add the "m" and "c" as an index to "R". I find it always a bit fiddly to use expressions in plots, especially if you want to get very fancy.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point()+
  annotate(geom = 'text', x = 20, y = 300, 
           label = bquote("R[m]^2 == 0.65"), parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. That really solved my problem. However, I do have two minor questions:
1. Is there a way to write everything in bold?
2. When I write "0.50" it is shortend to only "0.5". Is there a way to force it to also write the 0 behind the 5?

Comment: @T.Tree those might be worth follow up questions. expressions can be really fiddly, and at the moment I don't have enough time on my hand to look into it. Remember to link to your first question if you should decide to ask a follow up question, and include a reproducible example such as in my answer above.