# Annotate shortens numbers which end with a 0 and can not be written in bold

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

Hi together this is a following up question to this one:
[Add an aditional letter to R squared for annotate in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683873/add-an-aditional-letter-to-r-squared-for-annotate-in-ggplot/67874194?noredirect=1#comment120138550_67874194)

Here an example

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) +
annotate(geom = "text", x = 20, y = 300, label = bquote("R[m]^2 == 0.60"), parse = TRUE)
```

I would like the Code to write `R²m = 0.60` and not `R²m = 0.6`
The code always omits the "0" and as there are other R² values in the plot with a second number behind the dot it looks odd without the 0.
And do you have an idea how I can write these things in bold?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass 0.6 as character and use `bold()` in `label` to get bold text.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) +
       annotate(geom = "text", x = 20, y = 300, 
                label = bquote("bold(R[m]^2 == '0.60')"), parse = TRUE)
```

[image]